# Python subprocess terminal/space need to be adjusted to a value other than 80/24

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I am working on invoking and  executable as a part of script in python using subprocess.Popen. `subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. The executable need to open in a  subprocess terminal/window/space larger than 80/24 else the results get truncated. I need to adjust the input/flags to subprocess so that columns number is changed. I have tried `env= {'COLUMNS':'300'}` but that doesn't help.

I use python 2.7

Comment: You will need to use a pty so that when the program asks for the terminal size you can tell it how large to think it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen(command,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` executes a command and returns the result text.

```
import os

command = "some command"
res = os.popen(command).read() # get all content as text
res = list(os.popen(command)) # get lines as array elements
```

To change the terminal size, use

```
import os

rows = raw_input("rows: ")
cols = raw_input("cols: ")
os.system("resize -s {row} {col}".format(row=rows, col=cols))
```